# Can an SQLAlchemy ARRAY column be mapped to a python tuple?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have seen the SQLAlchemy ARRAY columns be mapped to lists with a default empty list value like this:

```
tags = Column(ARRAY(Text, dimensions=1), default=[])
```

Can this mapped to a non-mutable python object like a tuple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer in the [docs here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.ARRAY). Basically when you define an `ARRAY` column in `SQLAlchemy`, you can set the `as_tuple` argument to `True` to store the array values as tuples instead of lists. For example:

```
tags = Column(ARRAY(Integer), as_tuple=True)
```